# Have only one drop down panel open on click using HTML, JS, and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down menu list of links fixed on the left side of a web page I'm trying to build. I got the structure of the HTML and CSS [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol) on w3 schools, but fit it to my page. I like the way it came out because it's a smooth transition of opening the panel to show the links, however because it's fixed, if all the drop down panels are open you can't scroll down the screen to see. I originally wanted to have it scroll if it became too long, but I would much rather have it where only one drop down panel is open at a time. I would like that functionality like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_collapse) where I still keep the smooth transition of opening and closing panels. I'm still learning, so I don't know how to modify the code to do what I want so I was hoping someone can help me.  I would like to stick with just HTML, JS, and CSS. Here's the core pieces I'm using in my page.

CSS

```
ul {position: fixed;}

li {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li.drop-down {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0s;
}

div.drop-down-panel {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}

a.panel {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
<li class="drop-down">Header 1</li>
<div class="drop-down-panel">
    <a class="panel" href="#link1">Link 1</a>
    <a class="panel" href="#link2">Link 2</a>
</div>
<li class="drop-down">Header 2</li>
<div class="drop-down-panel">
    <a class="panel" href="#link3">Link 3</a>
</div>
<li class="drop-down">Header 3</li>
<div class="drop-down-panel">
    <a class="panel" href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    <a class="panel" href="#link5">Link 5</a>
</div>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down");

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You might also want to consider making your html valid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
<script>
   var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down");

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function() {
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            var maxHeight = panel.style.maxHeight;

            //Collapse all divs first
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down-panel");
            for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                 divs[i].style.maxHeight = null;
            };

            if (maxHeight)
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            else
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px"; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Updated code based on comment from @Mr. Bungle**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down");

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].onclick = function() {
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            var maxHeight = panel.style.maxHeight;

            //Collapse all divs first
            var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down-panel");
            for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
                divs[i].style.maxHeight = null;
                divs[i].previousElementSibling.classList.remove("active");  //new code to remove "active" class for all headers (li tags)
            };

            this.classList.toggle("active");  //Moved this line from top

            if (maxHeight)
            {
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                this.classList.remove("active"); //Added this line to remove "active" class for the current header
            }
            else
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px"; 
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: This one works well, but as mentioned, you can't unclose the same header again for some reason?

Comment: I think we commented around the same time, I tested it and it works like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: I was hoping I can get more help, the code worked as expected, but affects the style. Here's more of it https://jsfiddle.net/e7xez7rb/. When you hover a header it should change color. It has a +/- sign to signify open/minimize respectively. If the header is clicked the + should become - and should stay the given color until minimized and the - becomes a + again. However, if you open and minimize different headers some are still colored and have a - even when minimized and I don't know how to fix this. @PhaniKumarM can you help still?

Comment: @Mr.Bungle You can find the updated code above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/uoagaj4k/1/

```js
var prevClick = -1;
dropPanel = function(t){
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down");

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {  
    if(acc[i] === t){
     t.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = t.nextElementSibling;
      if(prevClick !== i) {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        prevClick = i;
      } else {
       panel.style.maxHeight = "0px";
        prevClick = -1;
      }
    } else {
     acc[i].classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = acc[i].nextElementSibling;
      panel.style.maxHeight = "0px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul {position: fixed;}

li {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li.drop-down {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0s;
}

div.drop-down-panel {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}

a.panel {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="drop-down" onClick="dropPanel(this)">Header 1</li>
  <div class="drop-down-panel">
      <a class="panel" href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a class="panel" href="#link2">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <li class="drop-down" onClick="dropPanel(this)">Header 2</li>
  <div class="drop-down-panel">
      <a class="panel" href="#link3">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <li class="drop-down" onClick="dropPanel(this)">Header 3</li>
  <div class="drop-down-panel">
      <a class="panel" href="#link4">Link 4</a>
      <a class="panel" href="#link5">Link 5</a>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Solution is using vanilla `JavaScript`.

Teo things to notice:

- Preserving the previous click (used for toggling)
- `onClick` method is added as an `HTML` attribute

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This would be better if it used unobtrusive javascript event binding and the HTML was valid. You can't have `divs` as children of `ul`

Comment: I tried it , but if you click to open the header 1, close it, then try and open it again, it doesn't open

Comment: The updated code works just as well thanks @Shiladitya !

Comment: @JonP can you explain why divs can't be children of ul? How can I make "valid" HTML?

Comment: While MDN is not the official spec it is often more friendly than the official W3C spec: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul .  Of particular note: **Permitted content, zero or more `<li>` elements, which in turn often contain nested `<ol>` or `<ul>` elements.** To make it valid, put the `divs` in the `li` (Official spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element)